# bash test builtin word regexp with =~ operator

Tags: linux, string, bash

How can I do that in bash? And is it possible to change [[ $1 =~ apple && $1 =~ banana ]] to something like [[ $1 =~ apple&&banana ]] ?

```
testme() { 
  if [[ $1 =~ apple && $1 =~ banana ]]; then
    echo 'contains both words'
  fi
}

testme 'apple banana' #should echo 'contains both words'
testme ' apple banana' #should echo 'contains both words'
testme 'apple banana '#should echo 'contains both words'
testme ' applebanana' #should echo nothing
testme 'apple cherry
banana 
pear' #separated by newline should echo 'contains both words'
testme 'apples bananas' #should echo nothing
```

Comment: what about `banana apple`?

Comment: Slow down there buckaroo, one question at a time - is your issue that the regex isn't doing what you want? All of the strings contain the substrings "apple" and "banana" so they should in theory all return "contains both words"

Comment: Technically, with the original (2-part) test, "bananapple" will match as well.

Comment: As for the ampersand placement, no, unfortunately, ampersands separate complete clauses- a bash test of 'banana' would yield True, your suggested change would be equivalent to something like 'if [[ $1 =~ apple ]] && [[ banana ]]`

Comment: Sounds like you want word boundaries, which the POSIX extended regular expressions bash uses don't support.

Comment: yeah I simple want word boundaries like grep -w does

Comment: like grep -q -w 'banana' <<< "$1" && grep -q -w 'apple'  <<< "$1" && echo 'contains both words'

Answer (score 4):

As @Shawn comments, bash's regexes don't support word boundaries. grep does:

```sh
testme() { grep -qFzw -e apple -e banana <<<"$1" && echo "contains both words"; }
```

This passes all your tests, as well as banana preceding apple.

---

If you want to stick with bash, here's a not-completely-terrible way

```sh
word_re() {
  local nonword='[^[:alnum:]_]'
  printf '(^|%s)%s($|%s)' "$nonword" "$1" "$nonword"
}

testme() {
  if [[ $1 =~ $(word_re apple) && $1 =~ $(word_re banana) ]]; then
    echo "contains both words"
  fi
}
```

or if you have a list of words:

```sh
testme() {
  for word in apple banana orange kumquat; do
    [[ $1 =~ $(word_re "$word") ]] || return
  done
  echo "contains ALL words"
}
```

Comment: I was about to hit post for one that uses perl, but I like the grep approach better.

Comment: Yeah, throw enough options at grep and something will stick.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I wanted to circumvent the extra call for grep and the stdin redirection, but unfortunately bash's =~ don't support this.

Comment: Just want to note, that you need to call grep twice in order to work

Comment: grep -qFzw -e 'apple' <<< "$1" && grep -qFzw -e 'banana' <<< "$1" && echo 'contains both words'

Answer (score 1):

While `bash` native regular expressions don't support word boundaries like you want (Without some uglier-than-normal hoops), if you can use `zsh` instead, you can do it purely in that shell without external programs like `grep`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

zmodload -F zsh/pcre 
setopt REMATCH_PCRE

testme() { [[ $1 =~ \\bapple\\b && $1 =~ \\bbanana\\b ]] && echo "contains both words"; }

testme 'apple banana' #should echo 'contains both words'
testme ' apple banana' #should echo 'contains both words'
testme 'apple banana '#should echo 'contains both words'
testme ' applebanana' #should echo nothing
testme 'apple cherry
banana 
pear' #separated by newline should echo 'contains both words'
testme 'apples bananas' #should echo nothing
```

This makes `zsh` use the [PCRE library](https://www.pcre.org/) for matching perl-dialect regular expressions instead of the default Posix Extended REs. (Your version of `zsh` must have been compiled with support for PCRE; I don't know if all common OS `zsh` packages are; Ubuntu's is).

`\b` is `perl` RE syntax for 'match at a word boundry' (Note having to double up the backslashes to play nicely with the shell).

---

And for completeness, versions of the `testme` function that use other languages to do the matching (Though I think Glenn's `grep` version is superior to both in this case).

`perl`:

```sh
testme() { 
    perl -0777 -nE 'say "contains both words" if /\bapple\b/ and /\bbanana\b/' <<<"$1"
}
```

and to illustrate yet another flavor of regular expression, `tcl` (Which uses `\m` for beginning-of-word and `\M` for end-of-word anchors):

```sh
testme() { 
    STR="$1" tclsh <<<'
    if {[regexp {\mapple\M} $env(STR)] && [regexp {\mbanana\M} $env(STR)]} {
      puts "contains both words"
    }'
}
```